# Can someone please explain what is this line of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> I want to know what does this {:<15}{} mean?

```
def printResults(swimmers,timings):
        fmt = '{:<15}{}'
        for i in range(len(swimmers)):
            print(fmt.format(swimmers[i],timings[i]))
        
        print("The fastest timing is {}s".format(min(timings)))
```

Comment: ```fmt.format('1'):'1              '```

```fmt.format('12345123451234'):'12345123451234 '```

```fmt.format('123451234512345')':123451234512345'```

```fmt.format('1234512345123456'):'1234512345123456'```

Comment: [Advanced String Formatting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101) and [Standard Format Specifiers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#standard-format-specifiers)

Answer (score 1):

This is string formatting syntax. You can read about string formatting in:

1. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/format
2. https://pyformat.info/
3. https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

> The `format()` method formats the specified value(s) and insert them
> inside the string's placeholder.
>
> The placeholder is defined using curly brackets: {}. Read more about
> the placeholders in the Placeholder section below.
>
> The `format()` method returns the formatted string.

In your specific case: `{:<15}{}`:

The first `{:<15}` will insert the value in `swimmers[i]` with leading white spaces. The second `{}` will insert the value in `timings[i]` as is.

Answer (score 1):

If the length of `swimmers[i]` is less than 15 it will add white spaces so the length of `swimmers[i]` plus the added white spaces is 15 (try it will lower number, e.g. `'{:<5}{}'` to see how it works). If the length of `swimmers[i]` is more than 15, no white spaces will be added.